# Google Cloud Function - Unable to Disable Billing Due to Permission

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Currently I'm running a Google Cloud Function that is found here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#write-a-cloud-function-2

This function 'stop_billing' is supposed to stop billing when it exceeds a budget:

```
import base64
import json
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
PROJECT_ID = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')
PROJECT_NAME = f'projects/{PROJECT_ID}'
def stop_billing(data, context):
    pubsub_data = base64.b64decode(data['data']).decode('utf-8')
    pubsub_json = json.loads(pubsub_data)
    cost_amount = pubsub_json['costAmount']
    budget_amount = pubsub_json['budgetAmount']
    if cost_amount <= budget_amount:
        print(f'No action necessary. (Current cost: {cost_amount})')
        return

    if PROJECT_ID is None:
        print('No project specified with environment variable')
        return

    billing = discovery.build(
        'cloudbilling',
        'v1',
        cache_discovery=False,
    )

    projects = billing.projects()

    billing_enabled = __is_billing_enabled(PROJECT_NAME, projects)

    if billing_enabled:
        __disable_billing_for_project(PROJECT_NAME, projects)
    else:
        print('Billing already disabled')


def __is_billing_enabled(project_name, projects):
    """
    Determine whether billing is enabled for a project
    @param {string} project_name Name of project to check if billing is enabled
    @return {bool} Whether project has billing enabled or not
    """
    try:
        res = projects.getBillingInfo(name=project_name).execute()
        return res['billingEnabled']
    except KeyError:
        # If billingEnabled isn't part of the return, billing is not enabled
        return False
    except Exception:
        print('Unable to determine if billing is enabled on specified project, assuming billing is enabled')
        return True


def __disable_billing_for_project(project_name, projects):
    """
    Disable billing for a project by removing its billing account
    @param {string} project_name Name of project disable billing on
    """
    body = {'billingAccountName': ''}  # Disable billing
    try:
        res = projects.updateBillingInfo(name=project_name, body=body).execute()
        print(f'Billing disabled: {json.dumps(res)}')
    except Exception:
        print('Failed to disable billing, possibly check permissions')
```

However, whenever I test this function it returns me this log entry: **"Failed to disable billing, possibly check permissions"**

I have already provided Billing Administrator Access specifically to this Cloud Function's Service Account. But yet it doesn't seem to be disable the billing. What am I missing to get this function running?

Comment: Which IAM roles does the Cloud Function service account have in Cloud Billing (not the Clour Project but the Cloud Billing interface). Cloud Billing IAM is separate from Google Cloud projects.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Cloud Billing API.

After creating the function to work, we need to enable the Cloud Billing API.

here they have  mentioned it - https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#test-your-cloud-function